# Do I really need to load Roboto font when using MUI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, fonts, roboto

I can see from the Material UI documentation that the user is responsible for loading the Roboto font :

> [Material UI is designed to use the Roboto font by default. You may add it to your project with npm or yarn via Fontsource, or with the Google Fonts CDN.](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/#roboto-font)

> [The Roboto font will not be automatically loaded by MUI. You are responsible for loading any fonts used in your application.](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-typography/#general)

I tried one of their example projects (the [vitejs](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/vitejs) one). I can't see any loading of the Roboto font in this project.

When starting it using `npm run dev`, I can see the text is correctly displayed with the Roboto font despite the fact that I can't see any trace of this font in the index HTML page.

I didn't see any `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"/>` in the header. I also tried to find any `@font-face` in the inline styles without any success.

I'm wondering where does the Roboto font come from? Is it included by default in modern computers (I'm currently using Firefox on a Ubuntu laptop) ?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

*No -- you do **need** to install the Roboto font to use MUI, since it is configured with fallbacks (and you can override the Roboto usage [globally](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/)), but if you want to conform to [the used version of Google's Material Design guidelines](https://m2.material.io/) or have a more consistent cross-platform UI, you may want to.*

What you're most likely seeing is the fallback font *(your system's version of Helvetica or another sans serif font, if Roboto is not installed locally)*.  They do look somewhat similar, but upon closer inspection of the subtleties, you can see that the fonts differ. (Rounding, spacing, etc.)

**CodeSandbox - [MUI with Roboto loaded](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-with-roboto-q8wy3x?file=/demo.tsx)**
[image: enter image with Roboto loaded]

**CodeSandbox - [MUI without Roboto loaded](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-without-roboto-dvnlg0?file=/demo.tsx)**
[image: enter image without Roboto loaded]

### Pre-installed OSes

As far as I'm aware, [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roboto#Usage) is the only OS where Roboto is a pre-installed font.

Not installed by default:

- [MacOS Monterey Font List](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212587)
- [Windows 11 Font list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_11_font_list)

(I couldn't reasonably find a list of Ubuntu pre-installed fonts)

### Confirming on Firefox

On Firefox the rendered (used) font can be seen by inspecting an element, then viewing the "Fonts Used" section of the "Fonts" panel.

### Confirming on Chrome

On Chrome the rendered (used) font can be seen by inspecting an element, then viewing the "Rendered Fonts" section of the "Computed" tab.

*Fun side note -- Firefox used to have quite a few [font loading/rendering problems](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1331797) which is why I **still** have trust issues using Firefox for dev.*

Comment: I don't see a fallback. When I go to the Fonts panel I can see that Roboto is used (without having installed it...) In your codesandbox example `MUI without Roboto loaded`, I also the `Roboto` in the font panel.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé And running `fc-list`, from the command line, on your Ubuntu box doesn't show `Roboto` installed locally?

Comment: yes it does, so Roboto is indeed installed on my computer, that's why the font is correctly displayed despite the fact that it's not loaded in the project